# how to increase only the height of Text Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Text widget each time I change the size of the Text widget it keeps increasing in width and height, but i want to only Increase the Height of the Text widget.

Comment: Is this what you want? [StrutStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/StrutStyle-class.html)

Comment: No.. i am try this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make it by using the Transfrom widget.

#### Example

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(1.0, 1.5),
              child: const Text(
                'Transformed Text',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            const Text('Default Text'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can  adjust in xml file to set height and width differently